# Oracle APEX cannot save a value into a session

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a page item `P2_ITEM_TYPE_ID` that gets set in Pre-Render, using a process calling PL/SQL:

```
BEGIN
   select ITEM_TYPE_ID INTO :P2_ITEM_TYPE_ID from TABLE1 where ITEM_ID = :P2_ITEM_ID;
   exception
      when no_data_found then
        :P2_ITEM_TYPE_ID := null;
END;
```

Currently the record for that ITEM_ID does not exist in TABLE1 so the exception NO_DATA_FOUND is thrown and originally the ITEM_TYPE_ID is set to null.

Now I want to set the ITEM_TYPE_ID by clicking on one of the cards on the page, grabbing its ID and setting page item P2_ITEM_TYPE_ID to that ID.

I have a dynamic action that runs the following javascript when card is clicked:

```
var $item_type_id = this.data;
console.log($item_type_id); //prints out correect ID
apex.item("P2_ITEM_TYPE_ID").setValue($item_type_id);
 console.log(apex.item("P2_ITEM_TYPE_ID").getValue()); //prints out correct value

//set session state of P2_ITEM_TYPE_ID
apex.server.process ( "SAVE_HIDDEN_VALUE_IN_SESSION_STATE", 
{
     x01: $item_type_id,
     pageItems: "#P2_ITEM_TYPE_ID"
}, 
{dataType: 'text'} );
```

I know the code works, as the correct values get printed to the console, but when I check the session of the page, P2_ITEM_TYPE_ID is blank in session. What could be the problem?

It is almost as if something is preventing th value from changing. 
I have identical setup on another page with one small difference - the code in the pre-render does not include the exception part because there is always a record in TABLE1 for that ITEM_ID:

```
BEGIN
   select ITEM_TYPE_ID INTO :P3_ITEM_TYPE_ID from TABLE1 where ITEM_ID = :P3_ITEM_ID;
END;
```

But the rest of the code is identical and session of P3_ITEM_TYPE_ID changes without an issue

Comment: I think is the "session state protection" propertie, you need to set to unrestricted. previously I was thinking you are calling some process with apex_server.process, but SAVE_HIDDEN_VALUE_IN_SESSION_STATE is just a descritive name, right? there isn't a callback process with that name? You are using apex.server.process just to send the value to session, in this case I think the problem is that propertie in the item, if you change to unrestricted, should be works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `apex.server.process` for this, you can post the value of an item to the server with an **Execute PL/SQL Code** action that follows the javascript action you already have. Put the item name (e.g. `P2_ITEM_TYPE_ID`) in the **Items to Submit** attribute (set **PL/SQL Code** to just `null;`).

Answer (score 1):

If everything is the same on those pages, except the `EXCEPTION` part, well - there's a workaround: use an aggregate function, e.g.

```
select max(ITEM_TYPE_ID) INTO :P2_ITEM_TYPE_ID from TABLE1 where ITEM_ID = :P2_ITEM_ID;
```

It will prevent the query from returning `NO_DATA_FOUND` if there's no value for that `:P2_ITEM_ID` and will store `NULL` into the `:P2_ITEM_TYPE_ID`.

Comment: While this did help me to get rid of unnecessary line for catching exception in pre-render, it still did not populate P2_ITEM_TYPE_ID, unfortunatelly.

Comment: I created an additional page item - P2_ITEM_TYPE_ID2 on the page and filled by adding one exta line to my javascript - `apex.item("P2_ITEM_TYPE_ID2").setValue($item_type_id);` and it worked fine. How come P2_ITEM_TYPE_ID does not get populated in session?:(

Comment: Apparently, that wasn't the only difference between those two pages. Check whether types of P2_ITEM_TYPE_ID and P3_ITEM_TYPE_ID is equal; actually, compare *all* their properties.